# Security concern google verification html file

Tags: security

I have a security concern about keeping the HTML verification file (ownership) of Google Services.

For example (fake content): **www.mydomain.com/google701e071d75a18d9a.html**

With the content:

```
google-site-verification: google701e071d75a18d9a.html
```

**Is there any security implication?**

I tried to research but I did not find concrete answers. So, now, I´m appealing to your knowledge to instruct me in this issue.
I´m a novice, so... Understand my question as the one who wants to know and dispel a doubt.
Thanks.

Comment: `Is there any security implication?`. I do not see how this file can be a security concern.

Answer (score 4):

The file poses no security threat and since it is the generic google verification file, once you have verified it with google you can just delete it afterwards.  There's nothing of any significance in the file anyways, just a unique hash generated by google to identify you once for their verification purposes.

Answer (score 3):

The file is used to verify you own the domain you are trying to use Google's services on. If someone attempts to claim that they own the domain (for their own nefarious schemes) they will not be able to add the verification file to the root directory of your web server.

If they are able to create files on your web server you have bigger concerns to worry about than a Google verification file.